# Index Coverage Status: "Submitted and indexed", except it isn't

Tags: google, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

A couple of months ago I created a new property in the Google Search Console. We all know: Google takes his time and I patiently waited, checked now and then, until the status of my sites were updated to:

> **Submitted and indexed**

[image]
Great, I thought, and double-checked by typing `site:www.chor-cantissimo.com` into Google. However, no search entry appeared. So I triple checked by typing the URL without `site:` and typing in various keywords. No entry appeared.
[image]

Next I checked if it got somehow blocked by the `robot.txt` which, of course, made no sense anyway since the sites got crawled and "indexed" (at least their status said so).

Just to be a 100% sure I also hit up the URL inspection tool and this is what it spit out:
[image]

Well, it also said that the page was indexed, mobile friendly, blablabla. But one thing wasn't right. No sitemap was available. This makes it even weirder since I have submitted a sitemap and all pages are valid:
[image]

On the same site it also confirmed again that my pages should be indexed:
[image]

(Don't care about the excluded, it has nothing to do with it).

So how is it, that all my sub pages, as well as my main page, (so all pages) are indexed, but not indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your robots.txt is missing a Disallow/Allow-entry, it only has a user agent defined. Read more about it at https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en.

The content on your site is generated via jQuery. It is recommended that you serve Googlebot a pre-rendered page for indexing purposes, as there are significant drawbacks to serving it CSR (client-side rendered) content. You can read more about different solutions at https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/rendering-on-the-web.

If you still need to use jQuery, it's probably better to use a library from Google's CDN, as it will more likely be pre-indexed. 
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

Comment: Up vote for now (because this might be it) and I will accept the answer if it turns out to be the reason. To your point with pre-rendered pages: This is not in my hands. Normally I would use a framework like Vue CLI which ships with this feature. However, I didn't notice so far so I forwarded it to the according people. Thanks!

Comment: If I may add, (not answering the question, just an advice) there's absolutely NO need to add sitemap for such a small website.

Comment: @Mnea I agree, but in my opinion it seems cleaner to have a sitemap. And there might be no mandatory need but the expenditure is like 5 minutes or less.

Comment: Alright, the robots.txt is changed (and also submitted). Just for testing purposes I set it to `Allow: /`. I also requested a "re-indexing" and the whole site got crawled again. However, no change whatsoever...

Comment: @Aaron3219 As long as you're using a CSR-solution, all will depend on when/if Google has indexed the script-library you're using. As the pages will be near empty until then, which is keeping them from being properly indexed. An alternative solution would be to use a jQuery-library from Google's CDN, as that will more likely be one they understand. I'm editing the answer to include that part.